# SAS kernel does not work on Juypter

Tags: java, python, sas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Updated: This has been solved by the developer, and the issue would be added into trouble shooting in the further saspy description. For those who want to know the details, please see the link on github. 
https://github.com/sassoftware/saspy/issues/93
The simple solution would be:
1. Fix the register of SAS
2. Run the CMD by administrator identity.

I tried so hard to make the juypter talk to SAS. However, I failed in the last step. Can anyone help me with it. The R kernel and Python kernel works fine on Juypter.

For those interested, there is a discussion on github as well. 
https://github.com/sassoftware/saspy/issues/93

The error is:

```
The application could not log on to the server. The server process did not start.
SAS process has terminated unexpectedly. RC from wait was: 4294967290
SAS Connection failed. No connection established. Double check you settings in sascfg.py file.
```

Full error screenshot
[image]

This is my setting in the sascfg.py

```
cpW  =  "D:\\Program Files\\SASHome\\SASDeploymentManager\\9.4\\products\\deploywiz__94250__prt__xx__sp0__1\\deploywiz\\sas.svc.connection.jar"
cpW += ";D:\\Program Files\\SASHome\\SASDeploymentManager\\9.4\\products\\deploywiz__94250__prt__xx__sp0__1\\deploywiz\\log4j.jar"
cpW += ";D:\\Program Files\\SASHome\\SASDeploymentManager\\9.4\\products\\deploywiz__94250__prt__xx__sp0__1\\deploywiz\\sas.security.sspi.jar"
cpW += ";D:\\Program Files\\SASHome\\SASDeploymentManager\\9.4\\products\\deploywiz__94250__prt__xx__sp0__1\\deploywiz\\sas.core.jar"
cpW += ";D:\\ProgramData\\Miniconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\saspy\\java\\saspyiom.jar"

winlocal = {'java'      : 'java',
            'encoding'  : 'windows-1252',
            'classpath' : cpW
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: This has been solved by the developer, and the issue would be added into trouble shooting in the further saspy description. For those who want to know the details, please see the link on github. https://github.com/sassoftware/saspy/issues/93 The simple solution would be: 1. Fix the register of SAS 2. Run the CMD by administrator identity.